# jquery: the parent modal dialog textbox is not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

jquery ui.dialog 
  after open a modal dialog, if I will open another modal dialog again and close it, the textbox  is lock in the parent dialog. I can not resolve this problem.
if I open a non-modal dialog , it works fine,
but the parent dialog can be closed ,How to resolve it , thanks , waiting online

html:(dotnet mvc2)

```
<input id="btnDlg" type="button" value="open dialog"/>
<div id="dlg1"><%=Html.TextBox("txtName","can not edit") %><input id="btnShowDlg" type="button" value="dialog again" /></div>
<div id="dlg2"><div>the second dialog</div><%=Html.TextBox("txtName2") %></div>
```

jquery:

```
//first modal dialog
$("#dlg1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 350,
                width: 300,
                title: "The first dialog!",
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            })
//second modal dialog
            $("#dlg2").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                title: "This is the second dialog!",
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            })
//show the first modal dialog
            $("#btnDlg").click(function() {
                $("#dlg1").dialog("open");
            })
    //show the second modal dialog
                $("#btnShowDlg").click(function() {
                    $("#dlg1").dialog("options", "hide",true);
                    $("#

dlg2").dialog("open");
            })
```

Comment: @divid , lock means , is it getting disabled??

Comment: thanks for gov, the textbox is getting readonly, it is not editable after the second dialog closed

Comment: @divid , can you select that box with firebug and see what css property is getting disabled??

Comment: see this link also http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4075

Comment: to gov: it seems not disabled ,because the textbox backgroud is not changed, the textbox is readonly , can not enter some characters, I can not get the css propery "disabled",it is undefined. thank you again

Comment: @divid , you have two dialog boxes right, what happenings if you open second one first and first one second is it the same behavior , one more thing your code has can not edit as argument, what isthat??

Comment: @david do one more thing, tag your questions under jquery-ui , jquery-ui-dialog also there are lot of expert people in this forum they can easily fix the problem.

Comment: above code :at the bottom, $("#dlg1").dialog("options", "hide",true); it should be removed, this is my test statement.  I get the "disabled" and "readonly" property, it is false.  the code : alert($("#txtName").attr("disabled")); 
alert($("#txtName").attr("readonly"));  and the $("#txtName").attr("style")  is empty string

Comment: thanks for gov , although this problem is not be resolved

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out, just in case sb ever needs an answer and doesn't find one

One needs to change the `z-index` in CSS file  of `#btnShowDlg` to this (not exactly)# `638746`and then the fields within the modal preview are editable.. No need to change anything else :)

Just go to your css file, locate `#btnShowDlg` and either change or set `z-index:638746;`